# Ms Access install if not exist in computer

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have created windows form application based on MS Access 2007 database and created setup file also But the problem is, when install application its through exception if ms access not available in computer Is there any option during installation of my application Ms access should install automatically in pc if its not exist or any other way

Comment: that does not seem to have anything to do with programming at all, in particular with neither C# nor winforms.

Comment: Do not use MS Access. Switch to something royalty free. Like SQLite. You cannot just install some MS Product!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553365/ace-oledb-connection-to-access-runtime-2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To be able to use an access database file you don't need MS Access be installed on the users machine. That is a paid product, as part of MS Office.
2. Instead you could download and install MS Access data engine. You could add it as a requirement in your setup (how you do that depends on what you use as installer. With inno setup for example it would look like:

   Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\accessengine\accessenginefilename.msi"" /qb ...;
3. For what it is worth, if it is not too late for you, instead of access, use some other database, like SQLite, liteDb, ... There are 250+ databases out there to choose from.